# curl not uploading file - prot p required

Tags: curl

I'm trying to upload a file over FTPS and I'm getting the following message:

```
< 521 PROT P required
* Failed FTP upload: 521
```

I've been looking through the curl options and can't seem to figure out why. It can connect just fine, but the file isn't being uploaded. I saw suggestions on how to get the PROT P command initiated over an FTP client, but can't figure out how to do this via curl / linux command line.

I noticed that PROT P stands for "prot private" and PROT C is for "prot clear" and discovered that the --krb flag can be set to "private" or "clear" but when I try using the --krb flag I get the following:

```
curl: option --krb: the installed libcurl version doesn't support this
```

How would I go about getting support for the --krb command to work with curl - assuming that using that flag would resolve the PROT P issue? If that isn't the solution, does anyone here know what I can do to resolve this?

The curl command I'm using is:

```
curl -kv -T /path/To/File ftps://user:pass@address:port
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue was a mismatch between the server and the client trying to connect to it having a mismatch in protocols. The server is using TLS 1.2 which wasn't supported by the version of CURL used on the client. After upgrading CURL to the latest version, the problem was resolved.